# Code to remove all occurrences of a character from a string isn't working — but why?

Tags: c, string, algorithm

This is my code and prints error. I think it should work fine but there is an error with the squeeze function and I cannot find what.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char *s, int c);
int main(void){
    char s[]="kyriacos";
    squeeze(s,'c');
    printf("the new kyriacos is %s",s);
}



void squeeze(char *s, int c){
    int i,j;
    for(i=j=0; s[i]!='0';i++){
        if(s[i]!='c'){
            s[j]=s[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    s[j]='\0';
}
```

Comment: `s[i]!='0'` => `s[i]!='\0'`

Comment: I'm curious about your `squeeze` function. When you're calling it from `main`, the second argument you provide is a `char`, but the function is expecting an int. Also, in `squeeze` you never actually use that variable `c`. I think that you want `squeeze` to have the character `'c'` stored in the variable `c` when you make that function call, right? If so, change `void squeeze(char *s, int c);` ->`void squeeze(char *s, char c);`, `void squeeze(char *s, int c){` ->`void squeeze(char *s, char c){`, and `if(s[i]!='c')`->`if(s[i]!=c)`

Comment: What do you want to do? 'c' or int c? int c will be equivalent to ascii character

Answer (score 3):

Your function implementation has a typo. In the condition of this statement

```
for(i=j=0; s[i]!='0';i++){
```

there must be used character `'\0'` instead of `'0'`.

```
for(i=j=0; s[i]!='\0';i++){
```

And one more typo is in this statement

```
if(s[i]!='c'){
```

Instead of the character `'c'` you need to use the parameter `c`.

```
if(s[i] != c){
```

Take into account that string functions usually follow the convention that they return pointer to the target string.

So it is better to declare the function like

```
char * squeeze(char *s, int c);
```

Also instead of using the type `int` as the type of indices for strings it is better to use the type `size_t` because it is the type that the standard function `strlen` and results of the applying operator `sizeof` have.

Here in the demonstrative program is shown how the function can be implemented

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * squeeze(char *s, int c)
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    do
    {
        if (s[i] != c)
        {
            if (i != j) s[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
    } while (s[i++]);

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "kyriacos";
    printf("the new kyriacos is \"%s\"\n", squeeze(s, 'c'));
}
```

The program output is

```
the new kyriacos is "kyriaos"
```

Comment: Looks like it even works with the pathological `squeeze(s, '\0')`.

Answer (score 1):

The for does not know when to end. When it reaches the last letter of your word it just goes on. The solution would be : i < strlen(s) . To use strlen you must include string.h in the headers! Good luck!

```
for(i=j=0;i < strlen(s);i++)
```

or you could go with

```
for(i=j=0; s[i]!='\0';i++) // '\0' is the end string character
```

Comment: isn' `strlen` computed at each iteration and so less efficient that the original (intended) code?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed computed at each iteration.
To make it more time efficient you can just make

`int word_length = strlen(s);`

Comment: Note that `for (…; x < strlen(str); …)` is usually bad — unless the length of `str` changes in the body of the loop.  It converts the algorithm from linear (O(N)) to quadratic (O(N^2)) — which can be a serious problem if the strings are long.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
void squeeze(char *s, int c){
    int i,j;
    for(i=j=0; s[i]!='0';i++){
        if(s[i]!='c'){
            s[j]=s[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    s[j]='\0';
}
```

The `'c'` is a mistake; you want to use the variable `c`.  You also need to test for `'\0'` (rather than `'0'`) to terminate the loop.

```
void squeeze(char *s, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    }
    s[j] = '\0';
}
```

Blanks are cheap; use them.  The increment operators can be used (carefully) in expressions.

Answer (score 1):

A concern in addtion to other fine answers:

[@jacoblaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552574/code-to-remove-all-occurrences-of-a-character-from-a-string-isnt-working-but#comment76096167_44552574) points out issues relating to the type of `c`.  This is important when `char` can have a negative value, yet the value passed in is via `int c`.

```
void squeeze1(char *s, int c) {
  size_t j = 0;
  for(size_t i=0; s[i]; i++) {
    // This could be comparing a negative `char` against a int value like CHAR_MAX + 10
    if(s[i] != c) {  
      s[j++]=s[i];
    }
  }
  s[j]='\0';
}

void foo() {
  char s[80];
  fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
  int ch = fgetchar();  // ch has a value in the `unsigned char` range.
  if (ch != EOF) squeeze1(s, ch);
}
```

---

> C11 7.24 String handling 
>   ... For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` ...

The standard C library tends to treat `char` as `unsigned char` for comparison purposes so suggest alternate approaches

```
void squeeze2(char *s, char c) {
```

or

```
void squeeze3(char *s, int c) {
  ...
    if((unsigned char) s[i] != (unsigned char) c) {
```

Answer (score -1):

When u pass s in squeeze(s,'c') it onlypasses the address of the first char of the string. To access the value at address u need to dereference the pointer(use *).
To access the next value make the pointer s point to next address using (s++) i.e it points to next address where a new char is stored which is after 1 byte.
The problem is with the loop, u need to access the value at address.
s points to address of location where 'k' is stored.
s+1 points to 1 byte after the base address 's' (since char stores 1 byte. If it were an int it would point to base address+4 bytes.
.
.
s+i points to base address + i bytes.

I have corrected your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char *s, int c);
int main(void){
    char s[]="kyriacos";
    squeeze(s,'c');
    printf("the new kyriacos is %s",s);
}



void squeeze(char *s, int c){
    int i,j;
    for(i=j=0; *(s+i)!='\0';i++){//the error is here
    //u need to access the value at address using * operator instead u were    
    //accessing only addresses
        if(*(s+i)!=c){
            *(s+j)=*(s+i);
            j++;
        }
    }
    *(s+j)='\0';
}
```

Also note that normally when u pass a char in an function it is received by the same data type.But since an int is used the char 'c' is  converted into integer in this case 99 which is its ASCII value. So in loop where it compares whether the character is equal to c the machine also converts *(s+i) to an int value and compares both of them

Comment: Note: *(s+i)=s[i]

Comment: @VidorVistrom that actually doesn't worrk in dev c++

Comment: You're still comparing with `'c'` and not using the argument `c`.

Comment: Made the necessary changes